# Reading a file with fgetc stops unexpectedly

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that, given an input image "test.jpg", create a copied image "copy.jpg" in the same folder.

I already written that:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.jpg", "rb");
    unsigned char d;
    while((d = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
        printf("%u ", d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it goes in loop printing only 255.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`; you assign it to `unsigned char` and so `EOF` (usually `-1` — and specifically `-1` on your machine) is translated to `0xFF`.  Since 255 is not -1, you don't detect EOF accurately.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `EOF` does not fit in an `unsigned char` (otherwise reading a character of that value could not be distinguished from the end of file). You need to have `int d`.

Comment: ok i fixed it, the program copies the image. Now the question is what are the values ​​of the pixels and how can i put them in a matrix?

Comment: @Alex Nice, work on that and post another question if you can't solve it.